# Routing to multiple ASP.NET applications from another application

Tags: asp.net, iis, nginx

I have multiple ASP.NET applications running on a single IIS server like below.

HR app - 223.34.56.32:81

Accounting app - 223.34.56.32:82

CRM app - 223.34.56.32:83

Now, I do not my end users to remember or bookmark all these URLs. Another problem is that these ports (81, 82, 83) are not IANA approved so I do not want to expose them to the end users.

I want to build another routing application (using ASP.NET or nginx), which will do the following

223.34.56.32/HRAdmin.aspx requested - route the request to 223.34.56.32:81/HRAdmin.aspx. End user will see 223.34.56.32/HRAdmin.aspx in his browser

223.34.56.32/CRMHome.aspx requested - route the request to 223.34.56.32:83/CRMHome.aspx. End user will see 223.34.56.32/CRMHome.aspx in his browser

**My clients have not agreed to use host headers.** I have to make the apps accessible using this ugly looking IP.

I am a noob in this sector. I do not know whether this is actually possible. And what technology can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: why don't you use host header?

Comment: My clients have not agreed to use host headers